# Notion API - Create a Database using Notion OAuth or API Token

Tags: notion-api

Is it possible to create a new Notion Database using API (by Internal and/or External integration)?

Don't see it currently in the API docs. It will be a blocker for integrations that would like to export data to notion to a database that it sets up using APIs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of `Notion-Version: 2022-06-28`, you can [create a database](https://developers.notion.com/reference/create-a-database) as long as the integration has the `Insert content` capability and access to the parent page.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is not. The API is limited to only querying databases. There is no ability to modify, delete, or create them as of the current version (Notion-Version: 05-13-2021): https://developers.notion.com/reference/database